# Qt 5 C++ undefined reference to Class::function(QString, Qstring, ...)

Tags: c++, qt

i know this question has been answered in this forum before, but I need more specific help.

Here's the code:

sessionwindow.cpp

```css
#include "sessionwindow.h"
#include "ui_sessionwindow.h"
#include "session.h"
#include "utils.h"

#include <QStringList>

SessionWindow::SessionWindow(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::SessionWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setFixedSize(this->size());
}

SessionWindow::~SessionWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void SessionWindow::on_cancelBtn_clicked()
{
    close();
}

void SessionWindow::on_createBtn_clicked()
{
    QString min = (ui->isMin) ? "min" : "nomin";
    QString sp = (ui->spHidd) ? "nosp" : "sp";
    QString name = ui->sessionName->text();
    QString user = ui->skUser->text();
    QString pass = ui->skPass->text();
    Utils u;

    u.createSession(name, user, pass, min, sp);
}
```

utils.h (Where the function prototype is declared)

```css
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H

#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>


class Utils
{
public:
    Utils();
    ~Utils();
    void startSkype(QString, QString, QStringList);
    void createSession(QString , QString, QString, QString, QString);
};

#endif // UTILS_H
```

utils.cpp (Where the function is)

```css
#include "utils.h"
#include "session.h"

#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QVector>
#include <QDebug>

QVector<Session> sessions;

Utils::Utils()
{

}

Utils::~Utils()
{

}

void Utils::startSkype(QString user, QString pass, QStringList options)
{

}

void createSession(QString name, QString user, QString pass, QString isMin, QString spHid)
{
    sessions.append(Session(name, user, pass, isMin, spHid));
}
```

The problem is tha I can't compile it, it just throws an error: undefined reference to `Utils::createSession(QString, QString, QString, QString, QString)'

Sorry if I explained bad and thanks for the help!! :D

Comment: What's the command line you use to compile?

Comment: In utils.cpp, change `void createSession(,,,`  to `void Utils::createSession(,,,`

Comment: Why did you write "this->setFixedSize..."? Just called setFixedSize()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put `Utils::` in front of your method definition:

```
void createSession(QString name, QString user, QString pass, QString isMin, QString spHid)
{
    sessions.append(Session(name, user, pass, isMin, spHid));
}
```

should be

```
void Utils::createSession(QString name, QString user, QString pass, QString isMin, QString spHid)
{
    sessions.append(Session(name, user, pass, isMin, spHid));
}
```